# What is the minimum sample size required for time series forecasting with quarterly frequency?

Tags: size, forecasting, sample, minimum

I'm having a quarterly time series with 2-3 years of data (totally 8-12 data points - varies from case to case basis). I would like to understand the minimum sample size required to perform time series forecasting on quarterly interval series.

I have tried with 2 - 3 years of quarterly data and forecasted but I would like to know the recommended sample size for quarterly frequency.

Comment: Hi, what about going to stats.exchange, just visit the site and browse around

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will do!